# RESTfull API for website and admin panel

Tags: php, angularjs, codeigniter, api

I am going to build website with admin panel , it will have these features(news , pages , gallery, events, sliders , users login/registration)
i want to create api for the website and api for the admin
i will use angular to build the website and the admin 
and i will use codeigniter to build the api

**my questions is :** 
should i work with RESTfull api to build the admin or its not recommended and if yes should i use codeigniter or its not usfull in this case (restfull api)

Answer (score 1):

I have worked with codeigniter for many years. But to be honest the choice of framework really depends on the app you have in mind and its functionalities.
CI in general is very easy to learn and to begin where others such as laravel tend to have a bigger learning curve. However, they do have more advanced functions compared to CI.

Using angular for the frontend seems like the way to go now a days but for a backend using a RESTful API to connect with angular really depends on how further you are willing to go with the backend. What I mean is having an API would be good if you are planning on building something more that a web interface/page like may be an app as well for the backend. Then it could be beneficial in saving time because you can reuse the same code in your API when connecting through the app. Apart from that, I'd say it really depends on how well you know the client, the backend user etc.